# Why my web site was visited by ARPA?

Tags: web-crawlers

20 minutes ago a user-agent with [66.116.153.122](http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/66.116.153.122) IP address has visited my web site. It's domain is `rev.opentransfer.com.122.153.116.66.in-addr.arpa`. User-agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.11) Gecko/20101012 AskTbSPC2/3.8.0.12304 Firefox/3.6.11`. Language: `en-us,en;q=0.5,de-de,de;q=0.8`. Compression: `gzip,deflate`. Oh, and my domain name ends with `.name`. Why ARPA has visited me?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: Don't you know for what is used arpa?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not ARPA (Advanced Research Project Agency).  That's just DNS at work.  Here is a write-up on [The in-addr.arpa Domain](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Course/Section2/15.htm).